# How to use a redirect when using Scala Process Methods

Tags: scala, redirect, process

I have a file I want to process using an executable outside of a scala script. I was hoping I could perform a redirect as well, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
val fileToProcess = "/targPath/filename.txt"
val f = new java.io.File( fileToProcess )
if( f.exists )
{
    val outFile = fileToProcess + ".out"

    // Doesnt work
    Seq( "LogGen", fileToProcess, ">", outFile ).!

    // Works 
    val cmd = Seq( "LogGen", fileToProcess )
    for( line <- cmd.lines )
    {
        // Process lines
    }
}
```

My issue is that I don't need to deal with the line by line output. I just want to invoke this type of a method on a number of files to get the corresponding output files. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this?

```
Seq("LogGen", fileToProcess) #> new java.io.File(outFile) !
```