# Scala process different from bash?

Tags: scala

Why the following:

```
"find terraform -type f -exec sed -i 's/prevent_destroy *= .*/prevent_destroy = false/g' {} +".!
```

Fails with:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

Whereas it works all good in a shell.

EDIT:
Another exemple:

```
"echo 'someText' > someFile").!
"cat someFile".! // This doesn't print anything
```

Why I can't write in the file?

Comment: Could you post some more context? Like how the string is formed in the scala code?

Comment: @tom get posted one long scala expression.

Answer (score 3):

It's working for me if I use the Seq implicit conversion to ProcessBuilder rather than String:

```
Seq("find", "terraform", "-type", "f", "-exec", "sed", "-i", "s/prevent_destroy *= .*/prevent_destroy = false/g", "{}", "+").!
```

Note that you don't need the quotes around the sed substitution command.

Your way isn't working because of how Strings are converted. Take a look at the scala source code (scala.sys.process.Process.scala):

```
  def apply(command: String, cwd: Option[File], extraEnv: (String, String)*): ProcessBuilder = {
    apply(command.split("""\s+"""), cwd, extraEnv : _*)
```

It is splitting the String on whitespace, which is breaking your sed substitution command. Better to use Seq instead, to avoid this.

Comment: That's a good point but if I do `Seq("echo", "sometext", ">", "someFile").!` then `"cat someFile".!` We can see that the file doesn't contain anything.

Comment: @Joan `>` isn't part of the command, so you should either (something like) `Seq("bash", "-e", "echo sometext > someFile").!` or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503308/how-to-use-a-redirect-when-using-scala-process-methods

Comment: Yep, check out the documentation for more detail: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html
`def #>(f: File): ProcessBuilder` Writes the output stream of this process to the given file.

Comment: Are you able to use @dk14's suggestion of `Seq("bash", "-c", "your command here")`?

Comment: `Seq("sh", "-c", "your command here").!` worked perfectly thanks guys!